# Find the index of minimum number that is greater than key given of a sorted array, do these two functions return same result?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search, sorting, sortedlist

Give an array of integer has been sorted (non-decreasing order), we need find the **index of minimum number number that is greater than key given**, I wrote two functions, they're identical except the return lines.

**lo** and **hi** specify index of low and high one, inclusive

```
int minimum_index_greater(int *a, int lo, int hi, int key) {
    int left = lo - 1;
    int right = hi + 1;

    while (left + 1 < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;

        if (a[mid] > key) right = mid;
        else              left = mid;
    }

    return right;    -------> function 1
    return left + 1; -------> function 2
}
```

The first question is any of them is **correct** (return the right value) ?

The second question is, I **suppose** two functions are the same in this situation, they return the same value in every case. And I pretty sure about that.  Am i right or not ? please explain.

P/S : When I solve a problem on [Sphere Online Judge](http://www.spoj.com/). I need to find this value and solve the problem, use function 1, I got 97.72/100 point (which I have no idea why it isn't 100), use function 2, I only got 94.44. So I guess the problem is here

Comment: What do `lo` and `hi` mean? I guess the specify a range of indices to search in, but is `hi` exclusive or inclusive?

Comment: I'm sorry, lo and hi is low and high to specify range of indices, and they're all inclusive

Comment: in theory the two values returned will be the same. However it seems to me you got the initial value for left and right wrong. Are you sure you need to use `lo - 1` and `hi + 1` instead of `lo + 1` and `hi - 1`. I typically implement binary similarly and in my implementation the left end is inclusive and the right one is exclusive. This would mean you need to use `lo` and `hi + 1`(if both ends are initially inclusive).

Comment: I never code binary searches, I always copy them from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The initialization 'left = lo - 1' and 'right = hi + 1' is totally intent, because I want the left and right position are already **checked** in every iteration, that also why I set 'left = mid' or 'right = mid' at the end of iteration, because they were **checked**

Answer (score 0):

Check out [upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) function. It does exactly what you want (simple binary search). [Here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/) you have a great tutorial about it.